# CSS paddings and margins not working

Tags: css

I am having a problem with the following code. I cannot pad the logo (x12creatiΩns) down from the top. I have tried `top:10px` as above but it doesn't do anything.

### HTML

```
<div id='header'>
<span id='logo'>
    <a href="index.php" id="logo" class="menu" rel="menu">x12creati&Omega;ns</a>
</span>
<span id='sublogo'>Just another portfolio...</span>
</div>`
```

### CSS

```
span#logo {
font-size:2.2em;
color: black;
padding-left:10px;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px white;
top:10px;
}

a#logo {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

a#logo:hover {
padding-top:10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #555;
}

div#header {
background-color:#DDD;
width:100%;
height:44px;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-bottom-color:#CCC; 
}
```

Comment: It's better to use classes instead of ID's. Only use ID's if you're going to use Javascript for that specific div. For your problem, you can also place the logo in a div, and give the div a specific width and height and change the margin.

Comment: @45808: While your comment isn't *incorrect*, it's definitely too broad and perhaps misleading. There are reasons to use `id` over `class` that have nothing to do with `getElementById` convenience (assuming that's what you were alluding to).

Comment: @45808: Defeats the purpose of having ID selectors in CSS, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try taking off the `a`

Like this

```
#logo:hover{}
```

Or if you need to acces the anchor try this

```
#logo a:hover{}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `display: inline-block` to your `a#logo` - http://jsfiddle.net/tmaHx/1/ - and then you can use margins/paddings

```
a#logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to your `span#logo` declaration and and just add some top margin and that should work. Also, you're repeating your "logo" ID twice; Once in your `span` tag and again in your logo `a` tag, that won't validate.

Answer (score 0):

because `a` is an inline element you have to add `display:block;` then you can add margins and paddings !

Comment: Wrong - inline elements *can* have padding, and there aren't any margins being applied here.

Comment: Sure, inline elements can have padding, but it won't make them take up more space. Unless there is a background or border, it's impossible to notice. If you were planning on using padding to shift the perceived position of an inline element, it won't work.